# axWindowsMediaPlayer crashes when run for longer periods

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am not an expert on c# but just trying to churn out a quick solution.

Gist of the solution:
I have a sensor that sends a signal via serial port, and based on the signal the video played must be changed. It switches between two videos

It works as it stands now using axWindowsMediaPlayer. But unfortunately the app crashes after, lets say, 2 hours or so.

Here is the code that i use to change the video url when signal arrives

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying) axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = mainFile;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Initializing the player with this

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0;
```

I assume this his some adverse effect on the memory or something; just not expert enough to figure it out. ANy suggestions, is this the right way to change video url?

Thanks